# Desktop switching in KDE when I start an application in another acitivity

Tags: kde, desktop, kde-activities

I have an application which is forced upon start to Desktop 2 and acitivity B. If I am currently in desktop 1 of activity A and start this program, it opens in the right place, but my active desktop is changed to desktop 2 of activity A.

Is there some way to disable this?

Comment: Feel free to fire a bug report on bugs.kde.org, you're likely to find thousands reports there...

Comment: I did that, but no one looked at it yet.
If someone wants to follow it: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=307306